# data from jsp to dto is not transvere

Tags: java, xml, spring, jsp, servlets

Hi I am facing two problem

1. HTTP status 404  (!important)
2. When I select Run on server on one particular project 'Two different dynamic projects executes' .

   - HTTP Status 404
   - message /RealTimeCurValue/RTCurrValue.do
   - description The requested resource is not available.

### web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<display-name>Pavan</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>RTCurrValue.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>RTCV</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>



    <init-param>
        <param-name>ContextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/Spring/RTCV-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>


    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>

</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RTCV</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.to</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

### RTCV-servlet.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.fact.mvcApp" />


<bean id="RTC"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

    <property name="prefix" value="/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

### RealTimeCurrValueController.java

```
@Component
@RequestMapping("/")
public class RealTimeCurrValueController 
{
    @Autowired
    private RealTimeCurrValueService service;




public RealTimeCurrValueController()
{
    System.out.println(this.getClass().getSimpleName()+ "Created");

}


@RequestMapping(value="/RTCurrValue.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)

public ModelAndView realTimeCurrValueController( @ModelAttribute RealTimeCurrValueDTO dto , HttpServletRequest req)
{
    System.out.println("RealTimeCurrValue Controller Started ");

    CbBtc rtvcDTO = null;
    System.out.println(dto);

    if(dto!= null)
    {
        String cValue = dto.getCryptoCurrency();
        System.out.println("cValue-----" +cValue);

        try
        {
            rtvcDTO = service.rtcvService(cValue);
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        if(rtvcDTO !=  null)
        {
            HttpSession session =req.getSession();

            System.out.println(" Success");
            return  new ModelAndView("Welcome.jsp" , "value" , rtvcDTO.getAmount() );
        }

    }





    System.out.println("RealTimeCurrValue Controller Ended ");

    return  null;
}
}
```

### RTCurrValue.jsp

```
<form action="RTCurrValue.do" method="post">
    Currency: <input type="text" name="currency"   />

    <input type= "submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

Comment: where are your jsp views? tree the directory project, if you can

Comment: You might put JSP files inside some other folder , which you doesn't configure as Viewresolver

Answer (score 0):

Your form action is relative to the current page i.e. `/RTCurrValue`, so the url used to post the form is `"/RTCurrValue/RTCurrValue.do"` which is giving the 404.

If your web app is running as the ROOT web app then try adding a / to the form action. `action="/RTCurrValue.do"`.

If your web app is running in some other context then add the context to the action. `action="/someContext/RTCurrValue.do`"

Or better construct the URL using the standard tags.

> <c:url var="formAction" value="/RTCurrValue.do"/>
>       <form action="${formAction}" method="post">

Comment: Hi can i use @Autowired annotation  twice in single class.                                                                                                In RealTimeCurrValueController.java   I have used    CbBtc rtvcDTO = null;    
 can I use like this    Autowired  private CbBtc rtvcDTO;    in addition to      Autowired
    private RealTimeCurrValueService service;